# Is there a way to convert multiple columns at once from string to text, or to other data formats?

Tags: qgis, data, convert, format, text

I have multiple data fields that need to be converted from string to text files. When I save them as "text" in excel or open office, they still load up as string files in **QGIS**. How can I convert more than one column at once from string to text (or even integer, etc. if the situation arises)?

Thanks for your help! 
Alex

Comment: which file format ?

Comment: See if this post from Anita Graser is what you need. [http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/](http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/)

Answer (score 1):

A string is just a sequence of characters as is text, for what you're doing they're bassically the same thing.

From dictionary.com

> String
>   16. Computers, Linguistics . a linear sequence of symbols, words, characters, or bits that is treated as a unit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the MMQGIS plug in. Under this plug in select "modify" -> "text to float" of "float to text" and select the columns you wish to change. The output will be a new shapefile where the columns types will be changed