# Selecting different field in attribute table for kriging in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, kriging

I have created a shapefile with several columns of data in the attribute table but I can not select any of the columns for a kriging except the 4 required to display (lable, northing, easting, elevation)

my attribute table is something like

```
well.id  northing  easting  elevation  data1  data2  data3  data4
```

I wish to krig the data in the data columns however my options for Z value field in the kriging window are only the first four column titles...

any suggestions?

Comment: What are the attribute types for the other columns (double, float, text, date, etc)?

Comment: Check if it it PointZ you are dealing with and get rid of it. Oops di dn't read it all. Disregard please

Comment: Sounds like your data1-data4 columns are not the correct data type for this function. As @StephenLead says, tell us what they are and we can advise

Comment: The fields are text, but I am unable to alter them in arc catalog... this makes sense that it would be the problem though!

Comment: changing the data type was possible using add a field and then using the field calculator, then deleting the old field... after generating the correct data format I should be able to krig without impedance, resolving an extension error now (spatial analyst worked yesterday!!!)

Comment: @ZiaRanks glad to hear that you resolved the problem. You should past your comment as an answer, so you can accept it and close this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type of the columns I wished to pass to the spatial analyst kriging function where of type "text"... text cannot be passed to kriging functions, and I needed to change these to integer values... I suppose a double would have also worked but I prefer long integer as some of the data was in the range of e^-5...

two possible methods to solve this issue are presented in [Changing data type in ArcGIS attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74470/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-a-data-type-in-the-arcgis-attribute-table)

as well as on the [ArcGIS help site](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34315).

I prefer the second, using the attribute table in either ArcMap or ArcCatalog, adding a new field, then using the field calculator to duplicate the values from the source column to the new destination column and choosing the data type in the options of this process... here is where I chose long integer...

for more information on the types of data in ArcGIS please see its [Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/geodata-953061022.htm)